# Sending an SMS Message with Rails and Twilio

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sms, twilio

I'm new to ruby and ruby on rails and having trouble setting up Twilio to send text messages.

So far I have the following code in my rails app: When I go to send the SMS message I get the following error:

```
Missing template twilio/send_text_message, application/send_text_message with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :slim, :coffee, :haml]}.
```

my initializer

```
#config/initializers/twilio.rb (removed keys)
require 'twilio-ruby'

  account_sid = "XXXXXXXXX"
  auth_token = "XXXXXXX"
  $twilio_phone_number = "+XXXXXXXXXX"

  $twilio_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
```

then added in the route

```
#routes.rb

post 'twilio/send_text_message' => 'twilio#send_text_message'
```

then i have my twilio controller

```
#twilioController
class TwilioController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def send_text_message
  end
end
```

and in my view I've set up a form for a user to enter a message that gets sent to my phone (because i'm in trial mode and it's verified)

```
#ShareWithWorld.html.slim

= form_for :twilio, url: '/twilio/send_text', method: :post do |f|
  =f.text_field "Hey"
  =f.submit "Send Text"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're getting that error is the fact you have no view to be rendered, e.g. `app/views/twilio/send_text_message.html.slim`.

If the code comes to the end of the action without an interrupt, it will try and render the associated view.

```
class TwilioController < ApplicationController
  def send_text_message
    $twilio_client.account.messages.create(
      :from => '+14159341234',
      :to => '+16105557069',
      :body => ..params from form..
    )

    redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Your SMS has been sent' # This is the interrupt that will make it so it doesn't try to render the view
  end
end
```

Comment: The code you wrote produces infinite loop. It sent +20 identical text messages before I was able to shut down the dev server. The culprit is the redirect. In my case it seems to lead to re-submission of the form that has initiated the controller action.

Comment: @Nick, if you're redirecting to the action that sends the text, it could produce an infinite loop. I probably shouldn't have made the assumption that `root_path` wouldn't be the action that sends the text message.